# React post to WordPress custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api, wp-api

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it but I have a react site using WordPress API as the backend. I want to store my contact form entries in WordPress so I created a custom post type

```
 register_post_type('contact', array(
    'supports'      => array('title'),
    'has_archive'   => false,
    'show_in_rest'  => true,
    'public'        => true,
    'labels'        => array(
            'name'         => 'Contact DB',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Contact',
            'edit_item'    => 'Edit Contact', 
            'all_items'    => 'All Contacts',
    ),
    'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-format-chat'
));
```

I am trying to keep it simple for now on the frontend and at least try store the title

```
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT}/contact`,
        {
          title: data.name,
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

This should not be protected or require authorisation as It is just meant to collect contact form entries and a user doesn't need to be logged in to create records. However, I am getting a 401 error

```
{
    "code": "rest_cannot_create",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a post via the default endpoint (at `/wp/v2/contact`) requires [authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) by default, i.e. in the API request, you need to include a user having the permission to create posts on the site, e.g. yourself.

Comment: @SallyCJ ah I see, thank you.  Is it possible to create a custom route that wouldn't require authentication (not sure if this is an option)

Comment: I think that since I am using react for the frontend I probably can't access that nonce on the server like I would with jQuery though as if this was a standard Wordpress setup?

Comment: @SallyCJ okay so what I have done is installed a JWT plugin and now with every request from the form I am sending username and password to an endpoint which generates a JWT token. I send that token back and then send it in the header of the request which works. But this seems a bit ridiculous. Surely I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. and not sure if you still need help, but you could actually store the JWT token in a cache to avoid having to request the token each time you make your API requests. And yes, you can [easily create custom REST API endpoints](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/), but I think you should just use the default endpoint/route for your CPT.

Comment: Also, JWT is not the only method you can use to authenticate your REST API requests, and in fact, WordPress 5.6+ has its own [application password](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) which can be used from a remote app/site. :)

Comment: Thanks Sally, I quite like JWT so I think I will look at that cache option. I will look it up but if you have any literature on that it would be appreciated

Comment: You can store the token in the browser cookies or [`localStorage`](https://javascript.info/localstorage). But if your front-end app is a mixture of WordPress and React like [themes using this](https://github.com/devloco/create-react-wptheme), then you could actually use the default cookie authentication. Have you already tried that authentication method?

Comment: @SallyCJ, thank you. I won't keep this thread going forever.. :) I took a look and the project you pointed to looks abandoned (last updated nearly a year ago). I am not sure if cookie auth or local storage is going to work because it is a contact form and pretty much every user that visits the site will be unique and need to basically authenticate once in order to submit the form and save the data to the custom post type. So, every request from every user will need to be authenticated so it seems like that can only happen at the time they submit the form. That is how I understand this anyway..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to make this a lengthy discussion... and sorry also about the last two sentences in my previous comment (I temporarily forgot cookie auth requires a logged-in user...). Anyway, I remembered something, so I posted an answer and I hope it helps? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not sure if this is the right way to do it

> I want to store my contact form entries in WordPress so I created a
> custom post type

It's not the only right way, but IMO, it is a good approach. :)

> It is just meant to collect contact form entries and a user doesn't
> need to be logged in to create records. However, I am getting a 401
> error

As I said in the comments, creating a post via the default endpoint (e.g. at `/wp/v2/contact` in your case) requires [authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) by default, i.e. in the API request, you need to associate a user having the permission to create posts on the site, e.g. yourself.

And if you visit the above link, the default authentication method is cookie-based which requires the current user be logged-in to your WordPress site, hence that method isn't suitable in your case since the contact form is available to everyone (registered/logged-in users and those who aren't).

So you might want to consider using application passwords instead, which in the past you'd need to use a plugin like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/application-passwords/), but with [WordPress 5.6+](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/), you no longer need to use a 3rd-party plugin. :)

But I'm not going to talk further about what authentication method should you use or how should they be used, however, I still wanted to say that if I were to authenticate my API requests via JS and the current user is not logged-in to WordPress, I think I would not use JWT because it normally requires us to send our WordPress password when requesting for a token and we certainly don't want to expose our precious password! :)

> This should not be protected or require authorisation

In that case, you can disable the authentication for your CPT's default API endpoint, and here's one easy way of doing it: Use a custom [`rest_controller_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters) for your CPT.

The steps:

1. Extend the [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/) and modify the [`create_item_permissions_check()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/create_item_permissions_check/) (which checks if a given request has access to create a post) like so:

   ```php
   // File name: class-my-wp-rest-contact-controller.php

   class My_WP_REST_Contact_Controller extends WP_REST_Posts_Controller {
       public function create_item_permissions_check( $request ) {
           if ( ! empty( $request['id'] ) ) {
               return new WP_Error(
                   'rest_post_exists',
                   __( 'Cannot create existing post.' ),
                   array( 'status' => 400 )
               );
           }

           return true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then set the `rest_controller_class` to the name of the above class:

   ```php
   // On 'init', load the above class file:
   require_once '/path/to/class-my-wp-rest-contact-controller.php';

   // Then register your CPT:
   register_post_type( 'contact', array(
       // ... your other args.

       'show_in_rest'          => true,
       'rest_controller_class' => 'My_WP_REST_Contact_Controller',

       // ... your other args.
   ) );
   ```

That's all, but feel free to futher customize the class (and just let me know if you need any clarification).

### Update

Note that the above steps would only allow unauthenticated requests to create draft posts with basic post data like title. So basically, those steps would only help in getting rid of the `rest_cannot_create` error (note the "create" vs "publish" below).

To create *published* posts (`post_status` = `publish`), the request would need to be authenticated, and if not, then you'd get an error with the code `rest_cannot_publish`.

But instead of having to authenticate, you can extend the [`handle_status_param()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/handle_status_param/) method in the REST controller class like so:

```php
public function handle_status_param( $post_status, $post_type ) {
    if ( in_array( $post_status, array( 'draft', 'publish' ) ) ) {
        return $post_status;
    }

    return parent::handle_status_param( $post_status, $post_type );
}
```

So in the above example, I'm allowing unauthenticated requests to set the post status to `draft` or `publish`, and for other statuses, I'm letting the parent class handle it.

And note that there are other permission checks done in the (parent) REST controller class, so you'd need to check the source for the relevant code should you get another error originating from that class, and then extend the method containing that code. (Remove, bypass or modify a restriction)

### Additional Notes

- If you intend on making the "contact" posts be published, then you should exclude the post type from search results by setting the [`exclude_from_search` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters) to `true` (or maybe just set `public` to `false`, then set both `publicly_queryable` and `show_ui` to `true`).

Comment: Thanks Sally, I really like this answer whereby I can disable the need for authenticating at all as it just doesn't make sense to have to authenticate for a contact form. I will give this a go and give you some feedback. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, take your time. 

Comment: So, I am not having much luck with this. I think I am putting the code for step 1 in the wrong place. I see you have a file name there but I don't actually know where in my files to put that file so I tried putting the code in my functions.php file and then I tried putting it into a custom plugin and neither worked. My custom post type register_post_type code is in a mu-plugins folder

Comment: Sorry, tried to edit the above but it wouldn't let me so here is the edited version... So, I am not having much luck with this. Not sure where to put the code from step 1 but I put it in a custom plugin but I still get the 401 error. If I remove the code from the plugin I created I get a 404 error instead. So, I think it is picking up the step 1 code in my plugin but for some reason I am still getting the 401 error (rest_cannot_publish). I have put this line into my custom post type which is in a mu-plugins folder `'rest_controller_class' => 'My_WP_REST_Contact_Controller',`

Comment: If your plugin is at `mu-plugins/your-plugin.php`, then you could put the custom REST controller class in `mu-plugins/includes` and do `require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/class-my-wp-rest-contact-controller.php';` right before you call the `register_post_type()`. Have you already tried doing so?

Comment: I have just done exactly what you said but still get 401 error `{"code":"rest_cannot_publish","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to publish posts in this post type.","data":{"status":401}}`

Comment: In that case, you might want to try deactivating all or some of your active plugins, specially those related to the REST API? And/or clear your site and browser caches, just in case.

Comment: The only plugin I have for the REST API is ACF to REST API(https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api) which will let me display the entries giving access to the ACF fields in the api. I tried disabling it but no difference. Otherwise I don't have any api plugins. I also cleared my cache and tried 2 other browsers. Same thing. I must be missing something...

Comment: Well, I guess then it's a theme issue?... (try switching to a default theme) But anyway, you can try my plugin [here](https://github.com/5ally/wpse-385769) - but firstly disable your MU plugin and then activate my plugin, then go to Tools -> Contact CPT API Endpoint Tester and follow the on-screen instruction.. I hope the plugin works, but if not, then maybe you should hire someone to check what's going on wrong.. or ensure your Axios/AJAX request is actually done properly?

Comment: Thanks so much for this Sally. I tested it out and your plugin works 100% but I still got the 401 error when posting from React. HOWEVER, I found the issue! I wanted it to be published by default so I had this `status: "publish",`. When I removed it from my post request data it worked! Seems like this was the issue the whole time! Seriously... Anyway, thanks again. Is there a way I can make it published by default?

Comment: Yes, you're right and I was actually about to tell you why that "publish" error happens :) So I'm sorry for having wasted your time with those troubleshooting.. I wasn't really paying attention to the error code (`rest_cannot_publish`) and just focused on the status code (`401`).. I guess I need a new spectacles! :p Anyway, I've just added an update to my answer and if you want, you can also try my updated plugin. :)

Comment: Not wasting my time at all, I am really grateful for your help! Thanks again so much for everything :)